# How to scale a model with an animation already on it?

Tags: animation, transforms

I have a wheel model from a friend with a rotating animation on it, and I want to put it on my vehicle for a game, but its too big. So I tried scaling it, but when I go to play the animation, it reverts back to its original scale. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check if the wheel has its scale keyframed on the timeline. (If you only need the rotation animated, then there shouldn't be any scaling keyframed in the animation)
2. You can also parent it to an empty in which you can adjust the scale of the empty, The size of the wheel will also follow that adjustment.

Comment: Thanks! At first, I tried parenting a blank to the mesh, and that didn't work, so I tried parenting it to the bones, and this worked. Thanks for your help!